# Handle listbox values in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium. I just want to know if I am having some `excel` data. How can I compare it with any `listbox` value and select that `listbox` value while executing any script.

**I have following code:**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:/Bhavin/geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     WebElement val = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
     List<WebElement> months = val.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
     //System.out.println("values are "+months);
     for (int i=0;i<=months.size();i++){
         String value = months.get(i).getText(); 
         //System.out.println("values for the months are "+value);
     }
     ArrayList<String> month = readExcel(5);
     //System.out.println("months.... "+month);
```

Suppose I have stored an Excel column in an array list (`month`). How can I compare the `arraylist` value from Excel to the list value that I stored for f.b months and apply select command for the same.

Comment: did you need to validate the twelve months? or else you need to compare the values in value and month?

Comment: i want to compare excel cell value that i stored in arraylist with the value that i stored in a list... and if it is true... option from the listbox should be selected

Comment: @user1 are you asking how to implement `readExcel(int rows)` function ?

Comment: no...m done with readExcel(int colNo)... i got one column with month field... now suppose m dealing with html list box that is having month values... i stored those value into separate list....how can i compare them both n use click event for runtime listbox???